# Opencart change default value of list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, opencart

I have a list where you can choose an option. I need to change default value to my own. Is it possible in Opencart?

```
<div class="form-group required" id="form1">
   <label class="control-label" for="input-option227">Choose</label>
      <select name="option[227]" id="frmdocumentsForm-r1" class="form-control" wtx-context="0128A83E-7CFB-40AA-836C-8D17569841BF">

                    <option value=""> --- Please choose an option --- </option>
                                    <option value="17">AAAA</option>
                                    <option value="18">BBB</option>
                                    <option value="19">CCC</option>
                                    <option value="44">DDD</option>
                                  </select>
 </div>
```

I need to change value "17" -> "AAA"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change  attribute value  with loop . If you need replace only 1st value 17 check for if condition.

```js
$( "select > option").each(function() {
$(this).attr('value',$(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value=""> --- Please choose an option --- </option>
<option value="17">AAAA</option>
<option value="18">BBB</option>
<option value="19">CCC</option>
<option value="44">DDD</option>
</select>
```